# No one can access our website today using http, but can with https

Tags: https, http

We arrived at work this morning to find our website was 'down'.  It loads a blank white page with no messages at all.  It worked fine last night and we have made no changes.  (I am the only one who has access to make changes.)

It is very odd in that I can access it if I use the https prefix but, as soon as I try to use the normal http prefix (or click on any link on the https page that loaded), I get the blank white page.  I am using Firefox but have tried in IE as well.  I have tried from two different local computers and people have tried from elsewhere in the country with the same results.  I have also tried with Safari on Verizon's network.  So I believe I have eliminated our local machines and our ISP from the equation.  If it matters, I have also tried pinging our website from a command line and it responds quickly with no packets lost.

Our hosting company (Powweb) initially told us they can view the site just fine from their end but, upon hearing all the information from above, they escalated it to their top support priority level.  However, they have been looking at it for several hours.

**Question: No one can access our website today using http, but can with https- given the provided information, what could cause this and what do we need to do to fix the problem?**

This is catastrophic because we're an online retail sales company and it's the Christmas season!  Someone please help!!

Here is some configuration info:

CGI     Active

FrontPage Extensions    No

Logs    https://www.powweb.com/controlpanel/LogFiles.bml

Platform Type   Debian

MySQL Version   5.5.32

Perl Version    5.8.8

PHP Version     5.3

Sendmail Path   /usr/sbin/sendmail

Perl Path   /usr/bin/perl

PHP Path    /usr/local/bin/php

Nothing has changed with the .htaccess file in over a month.  (I can see that from the date stamp.)  Here are the .htaccess file contents though:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php


ErrorDocument 404 /404notfound.php


Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes


<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
RewriteEngine On
# view counter trap anyone trying to access admin
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/admin/"
#RewriteRule (.*) view_counter_trap.php [L]
# Begin Ultimate SEO V2.2d
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-(.*).html$ product_info.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-(.*).html$ index.php?cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-m-(.*).html$ index.php?manufacturers_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pi-(.*).html$ popup_image.php?pID=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-by-(.*).html$ all-products.php?fl=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-t-(.*).html$ articles.php?tPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-a-(.*).html$ article_info.php?articles_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-au-(.*).html$ articles.php?authors_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pr-(.*).html$ product_reviews.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pri-(.*).html$ product_reviews_info.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-f-(.*).html$ faqdesk_info.php?faqdesk_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-fc-(.*).html$ faqdesk_index.php?faqPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-fri-(.*).html$ faqdesk_reviews_info.php?faqdesk_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-fra-(.*).html$ faqdesk_reviews_article.php?faqdesk_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-i-(.*).html$ information.php?info_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-links-(.*).html$ links.php?lPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pm-([0-9]+).html$ info_pages.php?pages_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-n-(.*).html$ newsdesk_info.php?newsdesk_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-nc-(.*).html$ newsdesk_index.php?newsPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-nri-(.*).html$ newsdesk_reviews_info.php?newsdesk_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-nra-(.*).html$ newsdesk_reviews_article.php?newsdesk_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-po-([0-9]+).html$ pollbooth.php?pollid=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
  # IOSC mobile site
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mby-(.*).html$ mobile/all-products.php?fl=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mp-(.*).html$ mobile/product_info.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mc-(.*).html$ mobile/catalog_mb.php?cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mm-(.*).html$ mobile/catalog_mb.php?manufacturers_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mpi-(.*).html$ mobile/popup_image.php?pID=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mt-(.*).html$ mobile/articles.php?tPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-ma-(.*).html$ mobile/article_info.php?articles_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mau-(.*).html$ mobile/articles.php?authors_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mpr-(.*).html$ mobile/product_reviews.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mpri-(.*).html$ mobile/product_reviews_info.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mf-(.*).html$ mobile/faqdesk_info.php?faqdesk_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mfc-(.*).html$ mobile/faqdesk_index.php?faqPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mfri-(.*).html$ mobile/faqdesk_reviews_info.php?faqdesk_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mfra-(.*).html$ mobile/faqdesk_reviews_article.php?faqdesk_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mi-(.*).html$ mobile/information.php?info_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mlinks-(.*).html$ mobile/links.php?lPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mpm-([0-9]+).html$ mobile/info_pages.php?pages_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mnc-(.*).html$ mobile/newsdesk_index.php?newsPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mnri-(.*).html$ mobile/newsdesk_reviews_info.php?newsdesk_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mnra-(.*).html$ mobile/newsdesk_reviews_article.php?newsdesk_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mpo-([0-9]+).html$ mobile/pollbooth.php?pollid=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mn-(.*).html$ mobile/newsdesk_info.php?newsdesk_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
# End Ultimate SEO V2.2d
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  <IfDefine SSL>
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
  </IfDefine>
</IfModule>
# Fix certain PHP values
# (commented out by default to prevent errors occuring on certain
# servers)
#<IfModule mod_php4.c>
#  php_value session.use_trans_sid 0
#  php_value register_globals 1
#</IfModule>
IndexOptions -FancyIndexing
# Begin IP deny by View Counter from www.oscommerce-solution.com
order allow,deny
deny from 220.181.108.102
deny from 180.76.5.220
deny from 180.76.6.41
deny from 180.76.6.159
deny from 180.76.6.55
deny from 180.76.5.168
deny from 180.76.5.177
deny from 180.76.5.199
deny from 180.76.6.130
deny from 180.76.5.59
deny from 180.76.6.14
deny from 180.76.5.201
deny from 180.76.6.154
deny from 180.76.6.17
deny from 180.76.5.145
deny from 180.76.5.204
deny from 106.120.173.105
deny from 185.10.104.196
deny from 180.76.5.23
deny from 180.76.5.147
deny from 180.76.5.114
deny from 180.76.5.29
deny from 180.76.6.133
deny from 217.69.135.249
deny from 180.76.5.189
deny from 180.76.5.71
deny from 180.76.5.97
deny from 180.76.6.16
deny from 220.181.108.169
deny from 123.125.71.19
deny from 123.125.71.98
deny from 220.181.108.108
deny from 220.181.108.96
deny from 180.76.6.40
deny from 123.125.71.109
deny from 123.125.71.91
deny from 217.212.224.181
deny from 180.76.6.65
deny from 123.125.71.40
deny from 220.181.108.111
deny from 220.181.108.115
deny from 220.181.108.152
deny from 180.76.5.173
deny from 123.125.71.59
deny from 183.60.214.51
deny from 183.60.212.146
deny from 123.125.71.39
deny from 180.76.6.147
deny from 123.125.71.110
deny from 123.125.71.70
deny from 180.76.6.66
deny from 123.125.71.30
deny from 180.76.5.99
deny from 220.181.108.106
deny from 220.181.108.95
deny from 180.76.6.150
deny from 220.181.108.116
deny from 180.76.6.43
deny from 180.76.5.94
deny from 180.76.6.144
deny from 220.181.108.162
deny from 180.76.5.155
deny from 123.125.71.20
deny from 123.125.71.27
deny from 180.76.5.39
deny from 220.181.108.161
deny from 220.181.108.112
deny from 180.76.6.51
deny from 180.76.5.195
deny from 220.181.108.101
deny from 180.76.6.225
deny from 123.125.71.114
deny from 220.181.108.97
deny from 180.76.5.202
deny from 180.76.6.232
deny from 220.181.108.163
deny from 180.76.5.196
deny from 123.125.71.38
deny from 220.181.108.159
deny from 123.125.71.17
deny from 220.181.108.177
deny from 180.76.5.198
deny from 180.76.5.61
deny from 180.76.5.76
deny from 123.125.71.57
deny from 220.181.108.77
deny from 220.181.108.185
deny from 180.76.5.146
deny from 123.125.71.85
deny from 123.125.71.99
deny from 220.181.108.88
deny from 123.125.71.25
deny from 180.76.5.152
deny from 220.181.108.91
deny from 123.125.71.95
deny from 220.181.108.80
deny from 123.125.71.52
deny from 220.181.108.178
deny from 123.125.71.116
deny from 220.181.108.158
deny from 123.125.71.26
deny from 220.181.108.114
deny from 180.76.6.153
deny from 220.181.108.168
deny from 220.181.108.75
deny from 220.181.108.154
deny from 123.125.71.106
deny from 220.181.108.166
deny from 220.181.108.181
deny from 180.76.5.221
deny from 180.76.6.156
deny from 180.76.5.190
deny from 180.76.5.95
deny from 180.76.6.141
deny from 220.181.108.144
deny from 220.181.108.123
deny from 123.125.71.94
deny from 180.76.5.63
deny from 123.125.71.97
deny from 123.125.71.50
deny from 180.76.5.154
deny from 180.76.5.100
deny from 180.76.6.134
deny from 180.76.6.148
deny from 220.181.108.109
deny from 180.76.5.143
deny from 180.76.5.203
deny from 180.76.6.151
deny from 180.76.5.116
deny from 220.181.108.176
deny from 180.76.6.42
deny from 180.76.5.197
deny from 180.76.5.96
deny from 123.125.71.48
deny from 180.76.5.66
deny from 180.76.6.36
deny from 180.76.6.146
deny from 123.125.71.53
deny from 180.76.5.149
deny from 123.125.71.88
deny from 123.125.71.0/24
deny from 180.76.5.30
deny from 180.76.6.46
deny from 180.76.6.61
deny from 180.76.6.64
deny from 220.181.108.93
deny from 220.181.108.172
deny from 180.76.5.0/24
deny from 180.76.6.0/24
deny from 220.181.108.0/24
deny from 185.10.104.195
deny from 5.9.125.26
deny from 217.69.135.250
deny from 217.69.135.252
deny from 217.69.135.248
deny from 217.69.134.79
deny from 218.30.103.125
deny from 61.135.189.191
deny from 220.181.125.178
deny from 46.236.24.51
deny from 183.60.213.51
deny from 178.255.215.90
deny from 144.76.137.226
deny from 144.76.95.39
deny from 88.198.16.153
deny from 46.165.197.151
deny from 62.212.73.211
deny from 82.156.1.180
deny from 178.255.86.1
deny from 184.107.239.2
deny from 198.143.158.202
deny from 217.69.135.246
deny from 185.10.104.131
deny from 217.69.135.247
deny from 217.69.135.251
deny from 178.255.215.66
deny from 180.153.236.192
deny from 5.9.127.154
deny from 180.153.236.183
deny from 85.214.138.248
deny from 89.145.95.2
deny from 89.145.95.42
deny from 115.118.128.202
deny from 192.111.150.186
deny from 173.208.245.108
allow from all

# End IP deny by View Counter from www.oscommerce-solution.com
```

Comment: We would need more information in order to help. For example, what web server are you using? As well, what configuration do you have? For example, it may help to see any configuration and .htaccess files assuming Apache. As well, what software are you using such as the store-front or other important fact? Otherwise, we can only give some really wild guesses. Can you edit your question to include some of this information? It will help us to help you. BTW- Welcome to this site!

Comment: I have added the information that was requested.

Comment: Got it! I added some formatting to make it easier to read. Unfortunately, your question was put on hold. I will see what I can do to re-open the question.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I have edited the OPs question and actually added a specific question (taken from the header with some assumptions). If this is not right, the OP can edit the question and correct it to make clearer. Have I hit the mark?

Comment: Are you intending to use HTTPS? I assume so. Are you intending to use HTTPS exclusively? I do not see a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS which is customary. Did I miss it?

Comment: Most of our pages are unsecured.  It only directs a customer to secured pages if there is a need for security.  (Create an account, place an order, etc.)  I just happened to notice we could still access the back-end of the store, even though the front-end wouldn't load.  When I started thinking about what was different I came up with the idea to try https vs the http.  So, if I type https://, followed by replacementradios.com, for instance, it loads (albeit after some security warnings and a short delay) but typing http://, followed by replacementradios.com will result in a blank page

Comment: When accessing via HTTPS, Chrome gives me *NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID*. I am not sure what that is. Still looking.

Comment: Most pages are not intended to be accessed with a secure connection.  (Only pages that could have sensitive information about the customer: orders, addresses, etc.)  I am assuming the error you're seeing is a security certificate error.  I got them in Firefox.  I just clicked through them because I know I can trust our site and I wasn't going to be entering any secure data.  I just wanted to see if it loaded.

Comment: With HTTP, I am getting an 503 Service Unavailable error. Have you tried rebooting? Is this an option?

Comment: Has there been any script updates or changes or even new plug-ins or some kind of code change lately?

Comment: We are not self-hosted.  We use powweb as our webhost.  I will bring that error to their attention.  Did you get it in Chrome or where are you seeing it?  I don't see any error number in Firefox.

Comment: I cannot get to your log files. It requires a log-in. Are there any clues in your error log? I suspect you are seeing 503 errors there and it may give you a clue.

Comment: Yeah. I used Chrome and accessed developer tools. It looks like it is returning a blank page, but when I click Network, it gives me the error. This is usually a process limit error. The first recommendation is a reboot. Some suggestions are code and plug-in changes or additions that are misbehaving. This is real common on web hosts.

Comment: No script changes, plug-ins or code changes on our end.

Comment: Can you access your site from `http://65.254.250.161/~username/store/`? Replace `username` with your host login and `store` with your install path. If you can run your site that way it hints that the problem is with routing. If it still times out that way, its a sign that its host/server/apache side. Also I wouldnt recommend using the current SSL since its not for your company...its the shared host env one and causes nasty security warnings.

Comment: One quick solution you can do is to simply redirect the entire site to HTTPS which may not be a bad idea anyway. I would ping on tech support. It can be that something changed server-wide/host-wide that is casing your problem. I do not think it is your configuration- at least I do not see anything. 503 errors are server-side and I cannot imagine a configuration scenario that will effect it. I could be wrong. I am plumb out of ideas right now.

Comment: @dhaupin brings up a good point! It can be a router or firewall issue. You can know this (likely) if you are not getting errors in your error log files. Also, look for changes in your cPanel or other control panel.

Comment: Have tried accessing through Verizon and our ISP.  Several other people across the country have reported the same problem.  No orders coming in.  We're down for everyone.  It's not just here.

Comment: As for the SSL, we don't have a choice.  All our host offers is a shared certificate.  We have discussed switching hosts but have heard nightmare stories about that.  That's probably a whole different topic...

Comment: @Kevin Whaaa no SSL on shared? Your host is either amateur, lazy, or way behind the times if that is the case. But back to it, did you try that IP based link as a means into the files? I believe OSC should run it on first gen. Also another thing to think about is error logging level. Some platforms allow you to turn errors off, or reporting level may be too general so all you would see is a white page.

Comment: I must not be putting the right thing in that url.  I get a Forbidden message

Comment: Have you added or changed any advertising?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  We don't have any advertising on our site.  We discontinued use of an external Google Adwords advertising campaign about a month ago.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: We implemented some SEO changes about 6 months ago to hopefully improve our organic search rankings.  We haven't done anything recently.  The last change was a coupon code add-on that was implemented about a month ago.

Comment: I used WireShark to make an HTTP request to your site. The 503 error seems to be coming from: IP address: 65.254.250.161 - The Endurance International Group - domain name: 65-254-250-161.yourhostingaccount.com This is your domains IP address. So it is not a router problem. Are you in a position to reboot? It that an option?

Comment: I cannot reboot the server.  We are not self-hosted and we are on a shared server.  I have forwarded this information to the host but they are not addressing this in a timely fashion, in my opinion.  Thank you for your continued help on this issue.  I appreciate it.  I am in over my head and I know it...

Comment: The conversation (TCP/IP) looks okay to be except for a bunch of ACK requests which would be normal in this case. I think it is something that only your host can fix at this point. I wish I could find an answer for you. It is a fault on the server as far as I can see. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Has this issue been resolved?